# The sessionManagement on Spring-boot does't work

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I watched the samples of Spring-Security ,and I want to integrate whit my application  using Spring-boot，But I can still login twice or more at the same time,I don't  konw why Here is my SecurityConfig.java;I'm using Spring—Boot1.3.2RELEASE and Spring-Security4.0.3RELEASE.

```
package com.eexcel.branch.config;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import com.eexcel.common.service.distributor.DistributorService;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    public static String[] ignoreUrls = { "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**",
            "/assets/**", "**/favicon.ico" };
    public static String[] anonymousUrls = { "/registe**", "/login**" };
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends
            WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(ignoreUrls)
                    .permitAll()
                    //
                    .antMatchers(anonymousUrls)
                    .anonymous()
                    //
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    //
                    .and()
                    //
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    //
                    .and()
                    //
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    //
                    .and()
                    //
                    .rememberMe()
                    //
                    .and()
                    //
                    .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    .expiredUrl("/login?expired");
        }
    }
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationManagerConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;
        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        @Autowired
        private DistributorService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                    passwordEncoder);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override the equals and hashCode to maks sure that SessionRegistryImpl

```
List<SessionInformation> org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl.getAllSessions(Object principal, boolean includeExpiredSessions)
```

can get the sessions of the same Principal ,the principal is just the UserDetails